# Razer Pro Type Ultra Keyboard: How to use function keys without holding down fn key?

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, xfce

To alleviate my wrist pain I tried my first ergonomic keyboard: Razer Pro Type Ultra Keyboard attached to Dell Latitude E7440's usb1 port.

To my surprise the Function keys won't work if <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is not held down.
By default the function keys are for media functions, not the usual <kbd>F1</kbd>...<kbd>F12</kbd> that I heavily used for my IDE and other apps.

Here's the kernel messages when I attached it to the usb:
[image: /var/log/messages]

- I tried disabling media keys / functions in the BIOS, but could not find any.
- I also tried finding recursively `fnmode` in `/sys/module/hid_generic/drivers/hid:hid-generic/003:1532:0277.0008` to no avail.
- I tweaked around with Xfce's *Setting* -> *Keyboard*, nothing successful.
- I tried some keyboard combinations on the dell keyboard itself that involves <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>NumLock</kbd>, <kbd>Fn</kbd>, etc .. Did not have any effects on the razer keyboard.

`uname -a` outputs `Linux localdebian 4.19.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.208-1 (2021-09-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`lsb_release -a` outputs:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
```

Comment: apparently fn + num lock will toggle function key default mode

Comment: @Esther: Thank you for the pointer. I just tried and retried it, and the function keys are still acting like as if the fn key were hold down. I still had to hold down fn and press tue function key for it to behave like a normal function key.

Comment: Don't you need the razer keyboard driver ( https://openrazer.github.io/ ) in order to properly operate your keyboard ? (it seems you are only relying on the hid-generic driver)

Answer (score 3):

This solves the issue on Ubuntu:

1. Save the following lines at `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/50-razer-pro-type-ultra.hwdb`

```
evdev:input:b*v1532p027B*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_c00e2=f1
 KEYBOARD_KEY_c00ea=f2
 KEYBOARD_KEY_c00e9=f3
 KEYBOARD_KEY_c018a=f4
 KEYBOARD_KEY_c0227=f5
 KEYBOARD_KEY_c00b6=f6
 KEYBOARD_KEY_c00cd=f7
 KEYBOARD_KEY_c00b5=f8
 KEYBOARD_KEY_c0192=f9
 KEYBOARD_KEY_c0194=f10
 KEYBOARD_KEY_7003a=mute
 KEYBOARD_KEY_7003b=volumedown
 KEYBOARD_KEY_7003c=volumeup
 KEYBOARD_KEY_7003d=mail
 KEYBOARD_KEY_7003e=refresh
 KEYBOARD_KEY_7003f=previoussong
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70040=playpause
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70041=nextsong
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70042=calc
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70043=file
```

2. run `sudo systemd-hwdb update && sudo udevadm trigger`

Note that this does not work when the keyboad is plugged in with the USB cable.

Credit goes to [Simon Waloschek](https://github.com/sonovice)

--UPDATE--

Razer released a firmware update for this issue for Windows:
[Razer Pro Type Ultra Firmware Updater](https://mysupport.razer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/6217/)

Comment: Firmware update 1.03 fixes this. Apply the update on a Windows machine, afterwards you can use Fn+Esc to toggle your F-keys between media key mode and normal F-key mode.

Comment: This worked for me but the first line was changed to `evdev:input:b*v068Ep0278*` as I had a different ID.

Comment: thanks @rickythefox that worked! this was driving me nuts. i dont understand why  razer believes this is a "good" idea to be so different than anything the people want. reminds me a bit of vim on debian with its stupid visual mode. guess 99% of users disable that crap.